# How to change default filter search clause in service now platform?

Tags: service, servicenow

When we make a search for users or incidents the default search clause is "greater than or is" but i want to change it to "is" clause.
Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The property @Antonio mentioned is the only way to affect the default search behavior, but if you prefix your search term with an equals sign, it will do an exact match.

e.g. You want to search for London in the `city` field, just type `=london` in the search bar and you'll get an exact match.

You can also prefix with `*` for contains or prefix/suffix with `%` for a startswith/endswith.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be an option to do this. However, you can change the default search behavior to "contains" by creating a boolean property named glide.ui.goto_use_contains in your system properties.

[More info on this here](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/helsinki-platform-user-interface/page/use/using-lists/task/configure-default-search-behavior.html)

Comment: this worked for now thanks...but if you find any way to change the search clause to match the exact string then please inform me